# Symfony 2.8: embedded Media FormType Collection doesn't displayed

Tags: php, forms, symfony, media

i try to create embedded Media form in another FormType.

This is my Media Formtype:
namespace AdminBundle\Form;

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

    class MediaType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('file', 'file')
            ;
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Media'
            ));
        }
    }
```

And this is my other FormType:

```
    <?php

    namespace AdminBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class PegiType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('titre')
                ->add('media', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new MediaType(),
                    'required' =>false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'prototype_name' =>'media__name__',

                ))
            ;
        }

        /**
         * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Pegi'
            ));
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return 'adminbundle_pegitype_files';
        }
    }
```

I read on the Web if i need to add more media in the form, it was necessary to add a script js like this:

```
    var $container;
    var index = 0;
    function form_allow(div, elem) {
        $container = $('div#' + div);



        var $lienAjout = $('<a href="#" id="ajout" class="btn">Ajouter</a>');
        $container.append($lienAjout);


        $lienAjout.click(function (e) {
            ajouterCategorie($container, elem);
            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        index  = $container.find(':input').length;

        /*if (index == 0) {
            ajouterCategorie($container, elem);

        } */

            $container.children('div').each(function () {
                ajouterLienSuppression($(this));
            });

    }


function ajouterCategorie($container, elem) {
    var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, index)
        .replace(/__name__/g, index));

    ajouterLienSuppression($prototype);

    return index++;
}


function ajouterLienSuppression($prototype) {

    $lienSuppression = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');


    $prototype.append($lienSuppression);


    $lienSuppression.click(function (e) {
        $prototype.remove();
        e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
        return false;
    });
}
```

But nothing appears on the form. 
[image]
So my question is: How to make appear it on the form, and also allow the addition or deletion of live media files.
Maybe my Js file is note a solution. Is there a better solution?

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option `type`, but it's [`entry_type`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-type).Also it should be class name passed instead of object instance.

So instead of

```
'type' => new MediaType(),
```

Try with:

```
'entry_type' => MediaType::class,
```

Comment: Hey, Thank' for your help. Unfortunately it still does not work :/